# browser.runtime.onMessage not triggered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a firefox extension and I have the following code in the script.js :

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({book:book,link:book.reviewsLink,type:"getBSR"}, (response) => {
        console.log(response);  
//CODE 
});
```

In background.js :

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("HELLO FROM BACKGROUND");
    //CODE
});
```

The script.js prints immediately "undefined" but in the background the console does not print "HELLO FROM BACKGROUND" so the listener does not work. I have the same code on my chrome extension, the only thing that change is chrome.runtime insted browser.runtime.

I'm really confused because Mozilla documentation's code is exactly like mine.

Comment: Firefox WebExtension should simply do `return` in the listener (Promise is allowed) instead of calling sendResponse or returning `true`. As for the problem it sounds like you may have two listeners and a different one is answering first. Can't help further without trying the extension myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by wOxxOm, `browser` returns a `Promise` and `chrome` returns a `callback` function. That means:

```
// callback
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({book:book,link:book.reviewsLink,type:"getBSR"}, (response) => {
        console.log(response);  
//CODE 
});

// Promise
browser.runtime.sendMessage({book:book,link:book.reviewsLink,type:"getBSR"}).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);  
//CODE 
});
```

Also as mentioned by wOxxOm, there is not enough information there to answer properly. When does each one run, in which context etc